# Usar instância padrão do Form em outra classe

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, classes

Essa é minha classe `HotKey`

```
    public class HotKey
{
    private string nome;
    public HotKey(string nome)
    {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    private void Start_KeyPressed(object sender, KeyPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        Form1.StartClicked();
    }
}
```

E essa é minha classe `Form1`

```
namespace Teste
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        HotKey Start = new HotKey("start");
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void StartClicked()
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Started");
        }
    }
}
```

Quero que a função `Start_KeyPressed` chame a função `StartClicked` que está na instância do `Form1`

Como faço isso? Já tentei passar a instância do `Form1` como parâmetro mas não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Estou fechando a pergunta porque acabou que ela não era clara mesmo, só o AP poderia responder o que ele queria como resposta.

Comment: Na verdade, acho que está clara e pode ajudar outras pessoas...

Comment: Não só não está clara como o que você fez é uma gambiarra que sequer tem a ver com a pergunta, mas eu sei que você vai achar que resolveu seu problema, mesmo que isso não seja bem verdade e tenha causado um pior, mas também sei que não adianta discutir.

Comment: Desculpa, não quero transtorno... Obrigado por me avisar que está errado, pode encerrar a pergunta.

Comment: @Maniero Descobri uma forma para fazer isso e tenho certeza que não é gambiarra,  posso editar?

Answer (score 3):

Partindo do princípio que o resto da classe está implementada corretamente e que seja o próprio formulário que dispara o evento de `HotKey` basta chamá-lo pelo objeto recebido já que ele é justamente o objeto chamador:

```
(Form)sender.StartClicked();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/WinForms/CastForm.cs).

Tem que fazer o *cast* porque recebendo o objeto do formulário como `object` os métodos de `Form` não estarão disponíveis. Se isto é confuso para você precisa estudar herança.

Se não for isso aí a pergunta não pode ser responda só com estas informações.

Comment: Certamente devo estudar mais, não esperava que fosse algo complexo... Pensei que havia algum jeito simples que eu não conheça...

Comment: @AlanAssis complexo? Acho simples, pelo menos bem mais simples do que o que já está fazendo :)

Comment: Deixa eu ver se entendi, ao usar o (Form)sender eu consigo acessar o Form que instanciou a classe atual?

Comment: Não, você acessa o objeto da classe que chamou este método.

Comment: Então eu teria que chamar o método Start_KeyPressed através do Form?

Comment: Me deixou confuso porque o método Start_KeyPressed é chamado automaticamente quando o usuário clica em determinada tecla

Comment: Não sei, achei que você sabia o que estava fazendo, eu só respondi o que você perguntou, sobre outras coisas do seu código é o que eu falei, não tem como responder porque a pergunta não é sobre isso e não tem informações suficientes que ajudem responder.

Comment: Consegui, irei deixar resposta aqui para outros com dúvida

Comment: Com certeza, você tem mais condições de saber como resolver do que alguém que não tem todas informações necessárias.

Answer (score 0):

Para que a classe HotKey tenha acesso aos membros da instância do Form1, eu criei adicionei a seguinte linha a classe HotKey:

```
public Form1 f1 = null;
```

E na classe Form1, eu fiz assim:

```
HotKey start = new HotKey();
start.f1 = this;
```

Desse jeito, se eu desejar utilizar alguma função do Form1 eu preciso apenas fazer assim:

```
f1.DoSomething();
```